# How to do third column in the center in css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have three divs. how to do two div as columns but the thrid need to be center and one column without grid-area?

Like in the picture.

I have try:

```
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-row:1fr 1fr;
```

But its create four columns.. and not what I need..
[image]

Comment: Is using `flex` instead of `grid` an option?

Comment: Well, I prefer css grid, In flex I don't want to use width:50%..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a grid with 4 columns, each div should span 2 columns, and the last child should start at the 2nd column.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid > div {
  height: 20vmin;
  width: 20vmin: 20vmin;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  background: red;
}

.grid > div:last-child {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```